# How to render form with errors in generic detail view

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to render a generic detail view page with a form with errors

My post method in my generic detail view is

```
def post(self, request, slug):
    if 'submit-edit-roster' in request.POST:
        edit_roster_form = EditRosterForm(request.POST, team=self.request.user.playerprofile.team)
        if edit_roster_form.is_valid():
            edit_roster_form.save()
            return redirect ('tcl-team', slug=self.request.user.playerprofile.team.urlslug)
```

my edit roster form is

```
class EditRosterForm(forms.Form):
members = 0
team = None
sublist = []
playerlist = []
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.team = kwargs.pop('team', None)
    self.members = 0
    self.sublist = []
    self.playerlist = []
    super(EditRosterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    currentroster = Roster.objects.filter(team=self.team)[0]
    for member in Playerprofile.objects.filter(team=self.team).order_by('name'):
        if member in currentroster.players.all():
            self.fields[str(member.name)] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ROSTER_CHOICES)
            self.initial[str(member.name)] = '1'
        elif member in currentroster.subs.all():
            self.fields[str(member.name)] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ROSTER_CHOICES)
            self.initial[str(member.name)] = '2'
        self.members += 1
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    i = 0
    for member in Playerprofile.objects.filter(team=self.team):
        if cleaned_data[member.name] == '1':
            self.playerlist.append(member)
        elif cleaned_data[member.name] == '2':
            self.sublist.append(member)
        i += 1
    print(len(self.sublist))
    if len(self.sublist) > 2:
        raise ValidationError("Maximum of 2 subs allowed")
    if len(self.playerlist) > 5:
        raise ValidationError("Maximum of 5 players allowed")
    if len(self.playerlist) + len(self.sublist) > i:
        raise ValidationError("Team members must be a sub or a player")
    return cleaned_data
def save(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    print(cleaned_data)
    UpdateRoster(roster=self.team.GetCurrentRoster(), players=self.playerlist, subs=self.sublist)
```

When my form has errors I get

```
The view team.views.TeamEditView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

I know I need to add something to pass my form the form object with errors but can't find how to do this.

```
        if edit_roster_form.is_valid():
            edit_roster_form.save()
            return redirect ('tcl-team', slug=self.request.user.playerprofile.team.urlslug)
        else:
            # Render detail view page with form
```

Apologies if my question is incoherent, I'm new to django and stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add `request` as parameter to the render shortcut

Comment: I tried render('team/editteam.html', self.get_context_data, request) but it gave me the exception join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'method'

Comment: Could you post the else statement. Its possible that the form is invalid and the else condition returns None type (instead of Https response). Alternatively, add a simple `redirect('/home')` to make sure that it is not the issue